# Unable to deploy on payara 5.184

Tags: java, payara

I have a problem during deployment of .ear's and .jar's on Payara 5.184.

Until now we used Glassfish but since yesterday we moved to the Payara.
Up to this point applications deployed without any issues but since i've installed Payara, every attempt to deploy finishes up with error below. Whole Payara5 directory and it's contents has chown for payara user.

Centos7
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_332-b09)

```
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ejb jar [xxxxxxxx.jar]: it contains zero ejb. 
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:643)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:934)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:874)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

does anybody has idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: `Invalid ejb jar [xxxxxxxx.jar]: it contains zero ejb.` Seems quite clear to me.

Comment: `please check server.log` Did you?